# Efficiently combine dataframes on 2nd level index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two dataframes looking like

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([2.1,4.2,6.3,8.4,10.5], index=[2,4,6,8,10])
df1.index.name = 't'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','a',1),('A','a',4),
                           ('A','b',5),('A','b',6),('B','c',7),
                           ('B','c',9),('B','d',10),('B','d',11),
                          ], names=('big', 'small', 't')))
```

I am searching for an efficient way to combine them such that I get

```
                 0
big small t       
A   a     1    NaN
          2    2.1
          4    4.2
    b     5    NaN
          6    6.3
B   c     7    NaN
          8    8.4
          9    NaN
    d     10  10.5
          11   NaN
```

I.e. I want to get the index levels `0` and `1` of `df2` as index levels `0` and `1` in `df1`.

Of course a loop over the dataframe would work as well, though not feasible for large dataframes.

**EDIT:**
It appears from comments below that I should add, the indices `big` and `small` should be inferred on `t` in `df1` based on the ordering of `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the unknown index levels to be inferred based on the ordering of `'t'`, we can use an other merge, sort the values and then re-create the MultiIndex using `ffill` logic (need a Series for this).

```
res = (df2.reset_index()
          .merge(df1, on='t', how='outer')
          .set_index(df2.index.names)
          .sort_index(level='t'))

res.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
                [pd.Series(res.index.get_level_values(i)).ffill()
                 for i in range(res.index.nlevels)],
                names=res.index.names)
```

---

```
print(res)

                 0
big small t       
A   a     1    NaN
          2    2.1
          4    4.2
    b     5    NaN
          6    6.3
B   c     7    NaN
          8    8.4
          9    NaN
    d     10  10.5
          11   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting the level values and `reindex`:

```
df2['0'] = df1.reindex(df2.index.get_level_values('t'))[0].values
```

Output:

```
                 0
big small t       
A   a     1    NaN
          4    4.2
    b     5    NaN
          6    6.3
B   c     7    NaN
          9    NaN
    d     10  10.5
          11   NaN
```

For more columns in `df1`, we can just `merge`:

```
(df2.reset_index()
    .merge(df1, on='t', how='left')
    .set_index(df2.index.names)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply! Unfortunately this is not exactly what I am looking for since it removes the rows from `df1` which have no index in `df2`.

Comment: How do you know that `8` is under `(B,c)` but not under `(A, a)`? Or `2` is under `(A,a)` but not `(B,d)`?

Comment: Because of the order of the `t` index column.